# Does Postgres always update a row even if the previous value is the same as the next value?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose the following,

```
create table my_table (id bigint serial primary key, name varchar(55) not null);
insert into my_table values (1, 'john');

update my_table set name = 'john' where id = 1
```

Will a new row be recorded in such a case? I know Postgres uses the MVCC model, which is why I'm asking. Does this mean every update will be written on the disk (the log and the table)?

Would a good-practice solution to such a situation be,

```
update my_table set name = 'john' where id = 1 and name <> 'john'
```

Because if so, then I would have to always fetch the row before updating it, in order to know the previous value.

Comment: `jane` is not the same as `john`, so yes, of course the changed value will be recorded? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've been up for a while, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Even though your example does not follow the question, I think I can get what you mean. That being, if an `update` specifies a value that is the same as the existing value, does Postgres actually perform the update? Well **yes**, it makes the *update* and rewrites the row.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tESkULkq)).  
As for the second part *would it good-practice solution to such a situation*.**NO!** it would not. First off, what percentage of your updates do you expect this condition to happen? Seems it would be very very small percentage, your guard against it assumes extremely large percentage. Secondly, (I would argue more importantly) doing so would cause confusion on what the query is for - and thus should be avoided. Your prevention seems to be a *solution looking for a problem*.

NOTE: Demo references ctid. `CTID` is a system defined column that indicates the row's physical location in the table. See [docuentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html).